# Word for using third person to refer to the person with whom you are speaking

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Specific example:

Randolph: Let me guess, you've managed to convince yourself you're still in the right?

Heather: Of course, I always am.

Randolph: Using humour to deflect.

Heather: No, I was being serious.

**Randolph: And she thinks people don't like her because she's unattractive.  I love this girl.**

There are only two people in this conversation and no one nearby to hear.

Comment: Not-so-subtle passive-aggressiveness?

Comment: Are you sure the final quote isn't non-spoken? I can't find the original.

Comment: It is from a seemingly self-published book (the kind without cover art) at the library, so I doubt it would be online.  But it is spoken aloud, as Heather responds ironically, "Who?  I don't see any unattractive girls here."

Comment: You said it: referring to an interlocutor in the third person.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this would be called an **aside**:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aside

> 1. A piece of dialogue intended for the audience and supposedly not heard by the other actors on stage.
> 2. A remark made in an undertone so as to be inaudible to others nearby.
> 3. A parenthetical departure; a digression.

Your example doesn't *quite* fit any of the definitions as there's no audience, and it's spoken so the other person can hear.  Perhaps you could call it *"an aside to an imagined audience"*.

Comment: How do you know it wasn't intended to be heard by the other actors? It could be a form of sarcasm.

Comment: ..and judging by OP's latest comment, that confirms my suspicion.. they're basically flirting with each other

Comment: @Othya I said "it's spoken so the other person **can** hear".

Answer (score 2):

This word does not mean specifically what you are asking about, but it would be one example of an **affectation**, defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affectation) as:

> an unnatural form of behavior that is meant to impress others
>
> 1 a :  the act of taking on or displaying an attitude or mode of behavior not natural to oneself or not genuinely felt
>
> b :  speech or conduct not natural to oneself :  artificiality

Your scene seems to fall somewhere between the two sub-defintions, in that Randolph is speaking of Heather, momentarily pretending he is speaking to someone else, as though she isn't there.  This behavior is not necessarily "[un]natural to [him]self" but is unnatural to the norm for the situation.  In this case, it is "meant to impress" or at least to make her laugh.

I might borrow a bit from Max William's answer and write this as "Randolph took on the *affectation* of speaking to Heather in an imaginary *aside*, so as to continue the flirtatious nature of their conversation."